# OpenCV mouse_callback param

Tags: python, opencv

At first, sorry for my bad english.
I am trying to get a function that opens an image and returns the coordinate from where I clicked as a 2-wide tuple.

I tried a bit and resulted in the following code:

```
import cv2

coordinates = ()

# Mouse callback function
def mouse_callback(event, x, y, flags, param):
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        global coordinates
        coordinates = (x,y)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def open_image_and_get_coordinates(image_path):
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    
    cv2.namedWindow("Image")
    cv2.setMouseCallback("Image", mouse_callback)
    
    while True:
        cv2.imshow("Image", image)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if key == 27:  # Press 'Esc' key to exit
            break
    
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return coordinates

if __name__ == "__main__":
    image_path = "landscapeTestPicture.jpeg"  # Replace with your image file path
    coordinates = open_image_and_get_coordinates(image_path)
    if coordinates:
        print("Clicked at (x, y) =", coordinates[0], coordinates[1])
```

That's a test script and it works just fine. My problem is, that i have to  use a global variable (coordinates).
So my question: Is there a way that I dont have to use a global variable?

Thank you for your suggestions!